# Issues creating an associative array with another array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array, symfony-3.2

I'm trying to create an associative array in PHP using an Object.  The Object is values from a database, called Category.  It only has two values, an id and a name field.

This is what I have:

```
$category = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Category')->findAll();

$stuff = array();

foreach($category as $cat) {
    $stuff[$cat->getName()] = $stuff[$cat->getId()];
}
```

But I get this nasty error:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1

I should say that I am using Symfony 3.  Any help would be great.

Comment: I think this `$stuff[$cat->getId()];` should be this `$cat->getId();` Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track but you need to remove `echo` since you're not trying to output anything. You're also attempting to assign a value from the array you're trying to enter a value into.

```
$stuff[ $cat->getName() ] = $cat->getId();
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I just omitted the value and replace with $cat->getId() in stead of $stuff[$cat->getId()] and it worked

Answer (score 0):

You $stuff array has no index 1, so it will cause that issue.

This is caused by $stuff[$cat->getId()];, which should be $cat->getId();

```
foreach($category as $cat) {
    $stuff[$cat->getName()] = $cat->getId();
}
```